# MVC in Java console, GUI and Android apps

Tags: java, android, model-view-controller

I'm trying to make a class project in Java as a console app, GUI app and Android app. Project requierements say it has to be implemented using MVC, so if the teacher quits the View layer from i.e. Console app and puts it with Controller and Model layers of Android app, it should continue working. So my question is: Is this possible? I know console and GUI apps may work properly because they have full access to Java packages (io, net, JavaFX, etc), but Android is limited and I wouldn't have same packages I could use in desktop apps.

Thank you in advance for any comments or suggestions.

Comment: The frontend of an Android app is and Activity class, which loads a Layout, i think is not possible to use exactly the same code in Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not seeing any reason you cant achieve this. You should do the followings

- Identify components from each layer.
- While writing Model and controller make sure you pick the APIs which
  are available on all platforms.
- Design UI based on Platform.

You UI will talk with controller and pass the data to model as needed.

```
Class Controller{

 public void setData(String data);
public String getData();

}
```

On Android side use Activity to display data and take input from user

for console application just use `main` function to read write data from console.

For GUI application, it should same as Android application, just instead of Activity use Awt or other package which suits your need.

Comment: Thanks, this is the way I first planned it but I'm a newbie in Java so I wasn't sure if it was right, right now I'm trying to find a Java package that I can use to play audio files in both platforms (PC, Android). I'm gonna be asking several questions until I finish my project, but I know I'm in the right place. Thank you again.